# Unable to access "Tag" attribute value for 'describe-auto-scaling-groups' using AWS CLI JMESPath query command

Tags: arrays, arraylist, aws-cli, jmespath, aws-auto-scaling

- Purpose - To fetch list of `values` for "Tags" where '`Key==Project'`.
- Query - For `describe-auto-scaling-groups` - Trying to access the Tag attributes with 5 array items Tag[5] with each array having 5 fields (eg- `resourceid:foo resourcetype:auto-scale-group **Key:Project Value=ebiz** field4:<field4-value> field5:<field5value>`)

```
-"Tags" [5]
 > [0] {5}
 > [1] {5}
 > [2] (5)
 > [3] {5}
 > [4] {5}
```

```
{
 "AutoScalingGroups":
 [
   {
    "Tags": [
     {
        "ResourceId": "foo1", 
        "ResourceType": "auto-scaling-group",
        "Key": "Owner",
        "Value":"Biz1", 
        "PropagateAtLaunch": true
     },
     (
        "ResourceId": "foo2",
        "ResourceType": "auto-scaling-group",
        "Key": "Project",
        "Value": "ebiz",
        "PropagateAtLaunch": true
     },
     {
        "ResourceId": "foo3" 
        "ResourceType": "auto-scaling-group", 
        "Key": "logical-id", 
        "Value": "logical-id-value",
        "PropagateAtLaunch": true
     },
     {
        "ResourceId": "foo4",
        "ResourceType": "auto-scaling-group", 
        "Key": "stack-id",
        "Value": "stack-id-value", 
        "PropagateAtLaunch": true
     },
     {
        "ResourceId": "foo5",
        "ResourceType": "auto-scaling-group", 
        "Key": "stack-name",
        "Value": "stack-name-value", 
        "PropagateAtLaunch": true
     }
   }
  ]
}
```

When trying to look/filter for one of the field where `Key==Project` and output its respective `Value` it returns **null** as it is not able to look for the `Key==Project` is what I could makeout.

Command used -

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-name "abc" --query 'AutoScalingGroups[*].[Tags[?Key=='Project'].Value]'
```

When using the array number [integer] I'm able to get the value, but the array number will not always contain the required Tags' `Key==Project`.

Command used -

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-name "abc" --query 'AutoScalingGroups[*].[Tags[1].Value]'
```

So to make things more logical I wanted to ask why the `key==Project` is not accessible and how do I access the `value` for  `Key==Project` from any of the list/arrays available under the "Tags" attribute?

Comment: Are you asking how to extract `ebiz` from that set of Tags? If `[Tags[?Key=='Project'].Value` doesn't work, try putting `Project` inside backticks and put the whole expression in single quotes: `--query 'AutoScalingGroups[*].[Tags[?Key==\`Project\`].Value]'`

Comment: Ahh Silly me! You are right @john . we already had the --query under single quotes/ticks hence the Key=='Project' did not work. ```aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups--auto-scaling-group-name "abc" --query 'AutoScalingGroups[*].[Tags[?Key==`Project`].Value]'```- the `excape backtips` works well. Thanks for the quick help, Appreciate !

Answer (score 0):

As correctly suggested by @JohnRotensten - The ANSWER is:

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups--auto-scaling-group-name "abc" --query 'AutoScalingGroups[*].[Tags[?Key==`Project`].Value]'
```

The hint was to escape characters.